# Pgfplots: fillbetween, enlargelimits and soft clip have interesting interactions

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

Setup: TexLive 2018

Consider the MWE below, provided by one of my users. He complained that the pattern disappears as soon as `soft clip` was used. Creating the MWE we noticed the following

- If `enlargelimits` is removed, the pattern is shown
- If `enlargelimits` is enabled, but `soft clip` is disabled, the pattern is shown

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

I don't think the `enlargelimits` is relevant for the real use case, but we'd like to know why this happens

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width = 13cm,
  axis lines = center,
  grid = minor,
  xmin = -0,
  xmax = 1.05,
  ymin = -0.25,
  ymax = 0.45,
%   enlargelimits = {abs=0.04}, % if this is enabled the pattern disappears
    domain = 0:1,
   xtick distance = 0.1,
   ytick distance = 0.1,
   xticklabels = {,,},
   yticklabels = {,,},
]
\addplot [smooth, samples=100, color=black, thick] {x*(1-x)};
\addplot [name path=B, smooth, samples=100, color=black, thick, dotted] {x*(1-x)+0.06};
\addplot [name path=A, smooth, samples=100, color=black, thick, dotted] {x*(1-x)-0.06};
\addplot [
 pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black!50
]
fill between[of=A and B,
soft clip={domain=0:1} % if this is enabled and enlargelimits is
%enabled pattern disappears
];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After a quick look I first thought that you have found another instance of the already reported [bug #194](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/194/). But now I think that is because of numerical inaccuracies. There is no need to use `soft clip` when the plots to that you apply the `soft clip` have the same domain. So either removing all `smooth`es, enlarging the (normal) `domain` or decreasing the `domain` used in `soft clip` makes the example work as expected. Do you agree?

Comment: @StefanPinnow well, even if the soft clip domain is the same as the draw domain is the same, that should surely not remove the pattern. What is the reasoning behind that? And why is it `enlargelimits` that triggers it? Works just fine without it on the full domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a defect in the computation of `soft clip`: apparently the fact that soft clip and the plot domain are the same runs into some computational problem.

I will take care of the bug.

As a workaround, I suggest to use soft clip only if it actually differs from the plot domain (it has no effect anyway if it is the same).

Comment: I filed https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/210/

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why `enlargelimits` may have an effect on the combination?